# CNAME DNS delegation

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

Just want to confirm/correct my understanding of how CNAME delegation works

if I have a CNAME cdn.example.com in my DNS that points to a third party CNAME cdn.thirdparty.com, can that third party register an A record in their DNS along the lines of test.cdn.thirdparty.com ?

i.e can they register 2nd level subdomains if their name server is now effectively responsible for resolving cdn.thirdparty.com ? or can only register an A record for cdn.thirdparry.com ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CNAME is not a "delegation". It is what it says, a common name, so by `a.example.com CNAME b.example.org` you define *an alias* and say "`a.example.com` is an alias of the resource commonly known as `b.example.org`". No "subdomain resolution" happens or whatever; `b.a.example.com` is a completely different name than `a.example.com` and it will not resolve as if it was `b.b.example.org` unless you add it as CNAME too.

But, CNAME will not only redirect resolution of A records of an alias to the common name, but any type records. It just redirects all resolution, saying "whatever you wanted from alias, ask about common name and apply to alias".

You can add several such "subdomain" aliases or whatever and they will all work simultaneously:

```
# nsupdate -l
> update add a.example.com 10 CNAME google.com
> update add b.a.example.com 10 CNAME microsoft.com
> update add c.a.example.com 10 A 192.0.2.222
> send
> quit
...
$ host a.example.com
a.example.com is an alias for google.com.
google.com has address 142.250.150.138
google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:4010:c1c::65
google.com mail is handled by 10 smtp.google.com.
...
(all the rest google.com DNS entries)
$ host b.a.example.com
b.a.example.com is an alias for microsoft.com.
microsoft.com has address 20.70.246.20
microsoft.com has IPv6 address 2603:1030:b:3::152
microsoft.com mail is handled by 10 microsoft-com.mail.protection.outlook.com.
...
(all the rest microsoft.com DNS entries)
$ host c.a.example.com
c.a.example.com has address 192.0.2.222
$ host -t txt b.a.example.com
b.a.example.com is an alias for microsoft.com.
microsoft.com descriptive text "google-site-verification=uFg3wr5PWsK8lV029RoXXBBUW0_E6qf1WEWVHhetkOY"
...
(all the rest microsoft.com TXT records; there are many!)
$ host d.a.example.com
Host d.a.example.com. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

In this example I add these records, two of which are CNAMEs and then tried to resolve them. As you see, TXT and MX record resolution happens under CNAME too, not only A and AAAA. (I actually did these tests to obtain genuine output.) Also you see that last check didn't resolve (not as `d.google.com` or anything) — I hadn't added it, it just doesn't exist.